# Port scan fails when firewall is enabled

Tags: python, windows, networking, windows-firewall

I have windows client system environment , when i do port scan with below command i do not get response if firewall is turned on.

Q1. i would like to know if any method i can get response whenever if firewall turned on or not?
Q2. Any port is always open in a windows system so that i can get response.

Note: Disable Firewall option is not suitable for me as when ever i do change computer domain settings firewall turned on by default for domain Networks in firewall

[image]

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ClientIP = '10.xxx.xxx.xxx'
def portscanner(port):
    try:
        s.connect((ClientIP,port))
        return True
    except:
        return False
for x in range(8000,8003):
    if portscanner(x):
        print("Port is open",x)
    else:
        print("port is closed",x)
```

Comment: Why don't you use an existing tool like `nmap`?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not the place for question on how to use your firewall and on how firewalls work in general.

Comment: @KlausD.: but it is the place to ask how to use a specific programming language to achieve a goal. Sometimes the answer is "no, you can't do this, because firewalls won't let you know this information", but that doesn't make the question off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

When the port is blocked by a firewall, you can't detect the failure until a timeout. You can set a short timeout.

```
s.settimeout(1);
```

This will only wait 1 second before giving up.

Comment: sorry if my question is confusing , how do i know if that client system is reachable ? i believe with timeout still i get response as not reachable.

Comment: The firewall is blocking you. It's not reachable on those ports.

Comment: Either the machine responds or it doesn't. There's no way to tell why it doesn't respond, which could be because it's unreachable or because the firewall is blocking you.

Comment: got it , my intention is only to know if system is powered on. is it possible for us to make one port always enabled or make an entry in firewall one time so that it will be always reachable?

Comment: You have control over the system you're scanning? Configure the firewall to open the port you want to use. This is a system administration problem, not programming question. Try asking in SuperUser.com

Comment: Yes i have control over system that i scan ... okay i will remove the question from here.. i have tried adding port to exception, still did not have any luck...